# http post with ant for file uploading

Tags: ant

As part of my Ant build process, I'd like to upload files to a webserver via HTTP Post.  Ant only comes with an HTTP Get task. However, [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) seems to have an HTTP Post task.  The problem is that it doesn't have any Basic Authentication (like get does) or any way to specify a file upload (despite what the docs say, "rawFile" is not part of the distro).

My question is: does Ant Contrib's Post task actually support what I want, but in a non-obvious way (perhaps I have to do it by hand)?  Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) program called via an ANT exec task.

For curl examples read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I can do that, but it means that curl has to be installed, which means you can't just pull the build.xml out of svn and expect it to work. :(

Comment: I hear you, *and* to make you even more miserable using ANT plugins doesn't solve your problems unless you commit the 3rd party jars into subversion as well :-(

Answer (score 7):

I have created an Apache 2.0 licensed, full featured and easy to use ant http task.  It utilizes code java.net.* classes and has no third party library dependencies.

It can do POST/PUT with files or in-line entities, and has flexible options for setting required headers, authentication and status code checking for build failure on unexpected results.

http://missinglinkcode.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/apache-ant-http-task/

Comment: Oops, Alex > just saw your posting above me after posting my hint for Missing Link, hope you don't mind ;-)

Comment: The examples in the PDF for `<entity>` close the `<http>` tag with `</query>`. Just thought you should know. Thanks for the task though. Trying it out now! :)

Comment: Is it possible to name an entity? I'm trying to accomplish something like: `curl -u username -X PUT -F file=@/path/to/file.zip https://some/api/foo/42`. Currently I'm getting a 500 error, and I think it's because the entity is not named "file", this is listed as a requirement of the API. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

A new ant http task named "Missing Link" has been announced on the Ant User List, give it a try =
http://code.google.com/p/missing-link/

Comment: Missing Link looks perfect! Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ant tasks based upon jakarta commons http client :

http://fikin-ant-tasks.sourceforge.net/

also providing a http post task with authentication.

When using ant with exec you will open a new process outside the java vm.
IMO external processes should be avoided if possible.

P.S. : if fikin ant tasks / http post with basic authentication is broken
i would prefer writing a java class or even my own task with jakarta commons, see
[jakarta commons http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) , [sample for basic authentication](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/BasicAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup) [2](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/BasicAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup)

so it may run in the same vm as ant or maybe in a forked java process
you'll find several examples for file upload with jakarta commons httpclient via google..

Comment: I agree that using ant exec is ugly and I would much rather use pure java.  However, the fikin ant tasks are broken for Basic Authentication.

Comment: fikin's httpmpost task seems fail to work in multi threading mode. e.g.: threadCount=5 in for task

Answer (score 0):

There's an http post task in [Antelope](http://antelope.tigris.org/) but it doesn't appear to support Basic Authentication. :/

Answer (score 0):

There's also an AntLib in the ant sandbox [here](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/sandbox.html) that claims to do HTTP get and post. However, its authentication is broken also.

Answer (score 0):

I made a patch for ant-contrib that adds basic authentication to the post task. Hopefully it gets included in the trunk. In the meantime, you can build it from source and apply the patch yourself:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3110414&group_id=36177&atid=416922

Once you've installed the new ant-contrib.jar, just add username and password attributes to the post task and it should work just fine. The file uploading, I dunno...